# Zlib Compression of a large file by chunks in C#

Tags: c#, compression, zlib, deflate

I need some help with the zlib compression of a large file. 
My problem is that I cannot compress the file by chunk to the same level that I compress it in one go. The result of a compression when I do it by chunks is slightly bigger. However I need to compress files to be the same size as of doing it in one go. I have coded my application in C#. I appreciate if you could please have a look and give me your advice.
Note: I used both DotNetZip and SharpZipLib libraries and found the result of compression of these two libraries are different as well.

```
       int len = 1 <<16;
       int partSize = 5 <<16;   
       MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
       //ZlibStream streamCompressed = new ZlibStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, CompressionLevel.Default);
       DeflaterOutputStream streamCompressed = new DeflaterOutputStream(ms,  new Deflater( Deflater.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION, false ),len);
       try
       {
         using var sourceFile = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(FilePath));
         while ((bytesToRead = sourceFile.Read(chunk, 0, len)) > 0)
         {
           streamCompressed.Write(chunk, 0, bytesToRead);
           compData = ms.ToArray();
           ms.Position = 0;
           ms.SetLength(0);
           data = AddArrayToArray(data, compData);
           if (data.Length >= partSize)
           {
             //UPLOAD DATA 
           }
        }
        ms = new MemoryStream();
        streamCompressed.Flush();
        compData = ms.ToArray();
        data = AddArrayToArray(data, compData);
        //UPLOAD THE LAST PART OF DATA
       }
```

Comment: You are collecting all the compressed data in memory. So why not do it in one go and divide the final buffer later? How slight (How much exactly) is the change in size in total?

Comment: Our server has a limited memory (buffer) so we cannot compress the whole in one go. The idea is to compress each part and upload it to the cloud (using multipart upload ) until we have a whole file there.

Comment: Ok I will try to reproduce this and see what is going on. The code says that the uploaded content should the exact same size with the complete compression because you are not generating the zip header more than once.

Comment: Why don't you pass the upload stream (let's say HttpRequest's GetRequestStream()) into this method and directly compress into it?

Comment: I am not sure if I get your question right!  Actually, the files are located on a PC and we want to upload them to the cloud. So I think I can not use httpRequest. Not sure!